# Short Term Effects of Orbital Decay

Tags: apocalypse, black-holes

The Earth has suddenly been decelerated, "bumped" into an unstable orbit. Guess you missed the jolt.

The velocity has been reduced such that the planet's orbit will hopefully restabilize between Mercury and Venus in approximately 100 years.

I'm not too concerned about the mechanism that caused the orbit to slow so much. A small black hole passing behind us sounds initially plausible.

Question: what are the environmental effects that we will observe over the next century?

Comment: *Between* Venus and Mercury?  I think the oceans and atmosphere would probably boil away, and we would end up a giant Mercury.  On a side note, what happens to the Moon during all this?

Comment: is that still within Goldilock's zone? I think if the Earth is "thick skinned" it will manage somehow like some of it's inhabitants lol

Comment: It's an apocalypse. The world is ending. Life will end. We will end up outside the Goldilocks Zone. But what will we observe over the next generation?

Comment: It will also effect the other planets, too.  How exciting.  I hope someone includes that in their answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Houston, we have a problem**
A single jolt cannot change the Earth's orbit in this way.

A single jolt will raise or lower the Earth's apastron (most distant from star) or periastron (closest to star) point of the orbit.

To give the Earth a new circular orbit (anywhere) requires **TWO** jolts.  One lowers the periastron to the new destination orbit and the second lowers the apastron to the new orbit.

[image: Hohmann Orbit transfer, courtesy of Wikipedia]

1. New lower orbit
2. Second jolt into new (circular) orbit
3. Initial jolt out of (circular) orbit

In astronautics circles this is technically called a Hohmann orbit transfer.  It is the minimum energy *direct* orbit change possible (some indirect orbit changes can use significantly less energy but they're tricky).  But we also call it a "Bang Bang" because it requires the two jolt events.

**Answering the Question**
My handy dandy planets spreadsheet shows that if you placed the Earth in Venus' orbit and changed nothing else, the equilibrium temperature would increase *on average* about 50 C.  To put this in perspective, Global Warming enthusiasts are worried about a < 4 C increase in average terrestrial temperatures.

Venus receives about twice the Solar heating that the Earth does, so I imagine this would happen in a relatively short period of time (hundreds of years).

Our civilization would end.  Except in certain special locations, I don't think humanity could survive this.  It is possible that plenty of other terrestrial life would survive but this would be a very major mass extinction event.

**Forces required to spiral into the Sun**
I get my numbers from this other SE answer on [how long until the Earth Spirals into the Sun.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/74569/how-long-until-we-fall-into-the-sun)

- Poynting-Robertson force (photons retarding our orbit) ~ $ 10^{17}
     years $
- Solar wind & bow shock ~ $ 10^{15} years $

These affects are so small on the Earth's motion, that a US Space Shuttle launched in the same direction as the Earth's motion has $ 100 \times $ the effect of the larger of these two.

In order to create a solar system environment in which the Earth begins a spiral into the Sun we'd need to pass through a gas cloud roughly $ 10^{13} \times $ as dense as the solar wind.

Solar wind density is ~ $ 7.1 \frac {nucleon}{cm^3} $

We'd need to pass through a gas cloud with a density of $ 7.1 \times 10^{13} \frac {nucleons}{cm^3} $

Unfortunately, the [densest clouds that we've spotted look to have about $ 10^6 \frac {particles}{cm^3} $](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_cloud#Giant_molecular_clouds).  So we fall short by 7 orders of magnitude :(

Comment: 1. You can't just slow the orbiting body significantly (removing energy) and have the orbit decay to a new stable spot? Interesting.
2. How long would there be between two jolts? Just 6 months (of the new months) or could a few years pass?
3. We'd have several generations to solve the problem as the temperature rose. That's promising!

Comment: You can do it with more jolts than 2, 2 is just the minimum it takes.  You *can* get a spiral decay but it requires something to constantly "drag" on the object (solar wind, photons, a molecular cloud, etc.).  But about anything that could drag on the Earth wouldn't have a measurable effect, given the amount of momentum in Earth's orbit.

Comment: You need one jolt at the beginning of the orbit change and one at the end.  You can have more jolts in-between these points.  For the Earth, the minimum time would be 6 months between jolts but the maximum could be any multiple of the 1/2 orbit (18 months, 30 months, etc.).  I'll have to double check on the drag issue, it is conceivable that a really dense interstellar dust cloud might induce enough drag if given enough time.  I'm just not sure that the densities required are in the realm of realistic.  Since my background is aero/astro, I should be able to calculate this and get back to you.

Comment: "Unfortunately"...or maybe fortunately??? The spiral orbit decay makes sense. I guess satellites are still in the atmosphere, and that's where I was coming from. How often does an orbit transfer happen?

Comment: We think planetary orbital shuffling sorts itself out early in its formation.  Most "changes" occur when two bodies have a close approach, one gains energy (usually the smaller one) and one loses energy (usually the larger one).  Losing energy lowers the orbit.  We can run gravitation models of our solar system backwards a billion years and see no interactions occurring.  But it is barely possible a stray planet (these get thrown out of solar systems frequently) makes a hyperbolic flyby and affects Earth just right.  The odds are nearly impossibly against it but it's possible.

Comment: Alternatively, the stray planet disrupts the orbits of multiple planets which causes a "dance" in the inner solar system which plays out over centuries or millennia before everything gets sorted again.

Comment: @Josiah - "You can't just slow the orbiting body significantly (removing energy) and have the orbit decay to a new stable spot? Interesting." Well, you can, technically. If the solar system were filled with a fairly dense gas, the earth's orbit would indeed decay, just as a satellite's orbit decays until it reenters. However, such "atmosphere" would get denser towards the sun, accelerating decay until the earth "reenters" - the sun. To stabilize the orbit, the gas would have to be absent from the stabilized orbit, and that ain't gonna happen with known physics.